# Which free 2D game engine for Ubuntu is the best choice for me?

Tags: application-development, games, 2d, engine

Which **free** game engines on Ubuntu would be the best choice for me to create **2D** games. 
The engine should **not** be **too hard** to use and support **multiplayer** if possible. I'd use it to create games with **graphics like TeeWorlds** in combination with Inkscape ofc.

I have tried **Löve** which is one of the free 2D game engines I find very interesting. It's available at http://love2d.org/. It uses lua for the programming language.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This is a fairly general question. Do you have a programming language in mind? Do you know how to program? Are you looking for something that is cross-platform? etc etc

Comment: I've tried Löve 2d game engine, which uses Lua as the programming language. It looks pretty much interesting, but still searching if there are any other good ones. Its no need to be cross platform.

Comment: This is a pretty subjective question. It's hard to qualify "BEST" since everyone's best is different. [Would you consider making this a software-recommendation question instead?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1872/how-to-run-the-software-recommendation-tag/1873#1873)

Comment: @MarcoCeppi You're right about the "BEST", everyone got it's own. I should rather ask, which one is the right choice for my type development idea. Secondly you must be right about this question being more a software-recommendation question.  Thanks

Comment: @sn0wex Feel free to edit your question to includes these new points - it'll help get you appropriate answers

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Thank you for your fast responses :) Appreciate it

Answer (score 7):

A good choice is [PyGame](http://pygame.org/), which you can use to write games in Python.

To get started, you can use [Quickly](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/quickly/):

1. Have a look at the [getting started page in the Ubuntu App Developer site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/) for a 5 minute quickstart
2. Use the PyGame template by running this command on a terminal: `quickly create ubuntu-pygame my-game` (where `my-game` is the name of the game you want to create)
3. Learn more from using PyGame on [this session](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeetingLogs/appdevweek1109/FreeformDesignGooCanvasPyGame) from the last [Ubuntu App Developer Week](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuAppDeveloperWeek).

Comment: Came here to post this, basically. It's a great way to prototype games, as well, as the performance may not be up to par with a dedicated engine in something like C/C++ but it's much easier to bang something out. That's a great use of Python, too--prototype in it, then optimize by converting to a lower level language.

Answer (score 0):

I am a non-coder and have very basic knowledge of programming. I found 'Stencyl' (http://www.stencyl.com/) to be perfect for me. I have tried some tutorials and found it simple enough to create basic games and found that it has the potential to make larger ones too. It is available for Ubuntu but requires the non free JVM to be installed.